Can I get and add durations to audios recorded with iOS Safari MediaRecorder that have no duration?
I have an issue with MediaRecorder output having no metadata on duration of the audio file using the simple code below (please use this JSFiddle on iPhone or Mac because the iframe on SO does not allow microphone permission). Or you can use the following file: https://github.com/user-attachments/files/16905190/ios-recording.zip
On Android, I used this answer to fix it already by parsing the EBML headers. On iOS, WebM is not supported and the output is an .mp4 file even though I only record audio. Is there any similar solution for this output file?


let recorder;
let chunks;

document.querySelector("#stop").addEventListener("click", () => {
    recorder.stop();
});

document.querySelector("#start").addEventListener("click", async () => {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: false,
  });

    recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  chunks = [];
  
  recorder.ondataavailable = function(e) { chunks.push(e.data); };
  recorder.onstop = async function() {
    const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: recorder.mimeType });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;
    a.download = "recording";
    a.click();
    
    for (const t of stream.getTracks()) {
        t.stop();
    }
  };
  
  recorder.start();
});
<button id="start">
  Start
</button>

<button id="stop">
  Stop
</button>




Where or how are you seeing that the MP4 has no duration? I see 01:27 as duration in Chrome audio tag.

@VC.One IIRC Chrome uses FFMpeg underneath. Indeed using FFProbe, I can get the duration correctly though I don't know how it does that, maybe it parses all the segments? Using a container parser like https://gpac.github.io/mp4box.js/test/filereader.html and loading the file, you will see that there is no duration header. I am parsing the file metadata using .NET with different parser, only FFProbe gives the duration as well and it's definitely isn't from the metadata.

The issue is even when I can get the correct duration with FFProbe, when I forwarded this file to another external API, that API acts as if the file is 1s long. Therefore I need to fix the file at client if possible
